# Background images not switching to alternate images on mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I've been working on my portfolio site (check it out at `www.imkev.in`) and I'm having some trouble with the mobile version.  I've got media queries in my CSS that should switch to a lower filesize and differently cropped image at any screen width below 530pxs.  There are other elements of the page (My multi column layout switching to a single column layout) that should similarly switch to a different page layout at lower screen widths and they do, so I know my basic media query is working. 
However, the background images elements do not.  They stay on the larger file and don't scale the image down to fit the browser window.  Again, I'm only have this problem on actual mobile devices.

When I reduce the browser window size on my desktop to below 530px it will switch over to the alternate images and the mobile device emulators I've been able to find online (Chrome developer tools and other browser based ones) all seem to work like they're supposed to.

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
.portfolio-background {
   background: url(/assets/images/background1-small.jpg) fixed;
   background-size: cover;

   @media (min-width: 530px) {
   .portfolio-background {
        background: url(/assets/images/background1.jpg) fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%; 
    }
}
```

I've also tried tweaking the background-size to be "cover" on the smaller media query with the same result.  I also have this at the top of my html file which should set the width of the browser window to be the width of the device being used:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I'm using a complier and I originally gave the code before my compiler did it's magic.  I've adjusted the post to show the actual code output.  Still trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background images are swapping correctly on your site, I think the issue is that are you not seeing the result you want because of the size and format of your mobile background, and your CSS rules.

The code on your site is slightly differt than what you posted, so I'll use that as an example.

First, try something like this for your mobile background:

```
body {
   background: url(/assets/images/background1-small.jpg) fixed;
   background-size: 100% auto;  
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I think you'll find that it's close to what you're after, but that it doesn't extend low enough at some viewports. The solution to this second point is to prepare another background image which is taller.

**Update**

> It seems like there has to be a better way to cover all the potential
>   screen sizes than having a different background image for all of them.
>   How do you get a responsive background image for mobile?

Background on mobile can be tricky because the format of the elements can change radically from their format on desktop.

- try preparing your mobile backround image so that its proportions are similar to the proportions on the element you want to cover on mobile
- sometimes you can us a background color in addition to your background image.
- if you can live with some of your background image not showing, then the use of [background-position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/) can help a lot. eg, if the center of interest is in the middle of your image, then css like the following will center your background image in the middle on your element

```css
element {    
    background: url(/assets/images/background1-small.jpg) fixed;    
    background-size: initial;      
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 50% 50%; 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: That sort of worked.  

Why doesn't: 

                 background-size: cover;

Work on mobile?  

It seems like there has to be a better way to cover all the potential screen sizes than having a different background image for all of them.  How do you get a responsive background image for mobile?

Comment: @KevinShewey, background-size:cover wasn't working well for you because it scales the image so that it covers both the height and the width of your element.  On mobile the element is tall so the scaled background image is wide as well, and that's the source of the problem. Try making the proportion of you mobile background image similar to the proportions of a typical mobile screen, say 2 wide x 3 to 4 high, and using the same CSS I suggested.

Comment: Correction @KevinShewey, try making the proportion of your mobile background closer to the proportions of the ELEMENT (on mobile) that you are trying to cover. Sometimes using background colours in addition to this approach can help as well. The background colour will fill-in the areas of the element that your scaled background image misses

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following link: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width

You are using the wrong media query. Instead change min to max. What this means then is that the maximum width is the one specified. So every decide whose width is less than or equal to 530px will use the styles you have specified.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be:

```
.portfolio-background {
  background: url(/assets/images/background1-small.jpg) fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

  @media (min-width: 530px) {
    .portfolio-background {
      background: url(/assets/images/background1.jpg) fixed;
      background-size: 100% 100%; 
     }
}
```

i.e. first the regular rules, then the media query, *inside that* the same selectors with the rules containing those parameters which differ from the regular rules.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using a compiler and I gave the code before it had gone through the compiler.  My bad!  In my actual CSS the output does read as you've suggested here.  I've edited my post to clarify.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Should be:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: That not only doesn't seem to fix the problem, it seems to cause problems with my background image not covering the whole area some of my other screen sizes.